# How to add action function to Disposable returned from subscribe on an Observable?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

You have an Observable, then you subscribe to it. The return value is a Disposable.  How do you add a function to be invoked when that Disposable instance is disposed?

```
clickStream.subscribe(....).dispose();
```

When dispose() is invoked I want to call a debug function, for example, console.log('Disposing ....').  In a real app, I would want to do some non-rxjs clean-up and UI notification actions.  Probably simple thing, but I don't see it in the API.  Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if `finally` would work for your use case ([documentation](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/finally.md)). According to the documentation, `Invokes a specified action after the source observable sequence terminates gracefully or exceptionally`. Note that this is not exactly the same as a callback being called when `dispose` is called but I thought that might be enough for your needs, and you can use it for clean-up actions.

**UPDATE**

Also close to what you want, but not quite so, you could use the `using` operator ([documentation](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/using.md)). It allows to create an object with a `dispose` method which would be called when the subscription to the associated observable is disposed of.

**UPDATE 2**

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/src/core/linq/observable/finally.js), `finally` actually executes the action when the subscription to its observable is disposed. This includes termination or manually calling `dispose()` on the subscription. That seems very close to what you want to achieve.

Best is to test. Please keep us updated of the results.

Comment: This is different than a dispose. `finally` fires either on an `error` or `complete` event. You can dispose an observable without either of those things happening.

Comment: These are the fine points of Rxjs and terminology is a bit confusing. I think you dispose only a subscription. Observables do terminate, error or emit values but they are not disposed. That being said, my answer is geared towards using `finally` to do clean-up and what-not in the absence of a better option. I agree this does not answer the question, but it could still be useful.

Comment: Fair enough. It might even cover OP's use case, depending on what he actually wants to achieve.

Comment: Though I think Peter Hall's answer is "better" in terms of the use case as I presented it, the use of the finally operator was enough for now.  I tested this by adding it to a click stream on an Exit button in a UI.   Puzzling, it is indeed invoked on dispose.   Thanks for all the feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Disposables are tied to event sources. The principle is that an event source is interacting with the non-Rx world, and might need to do some clean-up when no one is subscribed any more.

If you could put a hook into the `Disposable` that is returned from a call to `subscribe` then it wouldn't be of much use: you know when *you* called `dispose()` so you could just handle the clean-up logic there, and if some *other* code called `dispose()` it might be on a `Disposable` further down the chain, which may not affect your subscription.

It sounds like you are trying to make use of side-effects, which isn't necessarily in the spirit of the RxJS API. If you need to close down some network connection or something like that, then maybe you should be using a custom Observable, which creates a Disposable to clean itself up.

A simple example of this (simplified implementation of `Observable.fromEvent`) might look like this:

```
function fromEvent(obj, evt){
     var subject = new Rx.Subject();
     function listener(e){
        subject.onNext( e );
     }
     return Rx.Observable.create( function( observer ){
        var disp = subject.subscribe( observer );
          obj.addEventListener( evt, listener );
          return Rx.Disposable.create(function(){
             // All the clean-up code goes here
             obj.removeEventListener( evt, listener );
             disp.dispose();
          })
     });     
}


var events$ = fromEvent( button, 'click');
var count = 0;
var unsub = events$.subscribe( function(){
    console.log('click');
    count++;
    if( count > 5){
        unsub.dispose();
    }
})
```